# Axiom of Regularity and its application

Tags: set-theory

It is clear how this axiom works in case there is a set of which its members are natural numbers. I have also read that $\mathsf{ZF}$ applies only to mathematical objects. Question:

How does the Axiom of Regularity apply in a case where the members of a set are some other mathematical objects than natural numbers? Does it have to do with the definitions of the mathematical objects we are talking about?

Comment: In its most famous formulation, the axiom of regularity speaks of sets in a theory where every object is a set, and not of generic "mathematical objects". It's unclear to me what, in your own thoughts, is supposed to work for subsets of $\Bbb N$ that wouldn't for every other set.

Comment: For example in set theory natural numbers are defined in a very specific way(numbers are now sets).Based on that definition it is clear that this axiom makes sense. Let's assume that we are talking for the set: S={f:R-->R|f:linear}.In this case which member of the set has this property?

Comment: Then the axiom of regularity tells you that, whatever monstruous construction you've made to encode the elements of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ as sets (possibly as sets of sets of sets of sets of sets of sets... of sets of natural numbers), one element of $S$ does not contain other elements of $S$. You can kind of expect that a pair of real numbers isn't a (linear) function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, but of course when everything is a set that's not quite obvious (for instance, natural numbers are sets of natural numbers).

Comment: Oh i see,that makes sense. Approaching axiomatic set theory for the first time (having as a background only the naive set theory) this axiom, contradicts with the intention i have for sets. Seems very interesting though. Any idea or advice on how to get more familiar with these concepts?Your help is very much appreciated!